# Changing article height with @media query

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design, media, overlapping

I'm trying to change the height of the Twitter feed module you can see [here](http://chugiakhigh.asdk12.org/). The layout was done by the vendor we're using for our WCMS, so the CSS is proving a little difficult to navigate. I resized the iFrame for the feed so that it spans two rows, but now when it resizes for phones and tablets it overlaps the "Spotlight" article below it. [Here's the CSS](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98016068/app%20(3).css). Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @dippas That is not the problem. The problem lies in the fact that the parent element which wraps this `iframe` has a `max-height` of 320px which is why in the mobile/tablet view, the "content seems to overlap it rather than flow below it".

Comment: Changing the height corrected the overlap, but it also completely messed up the rest of the formatting. [Screenshot here](http://s3.postimg.org/blw19xbhf/2015_03_11_11_06_35.png). Any ideas? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clearing your floats with an extra div using clear:both it's best to get in the practice of clearing your floats in the parent container using overflow:hidden

The interim fix for the problem your having with your twitter iFrame overlapping your "spotlight" article is due to line 3568 in app.css where the max-height is specified. Removing that should fix the issue.

```
.home-content-modules-row .content-module {
    /*max-height: 320px;*/
}
```

Or maybe doing a media query to specify max-height:auto for that element when in tablet or mobile form.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
    .home-content-modules-row .content-module {
        /*max-height: 320px;*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing it will also cause the layout to change on the desktop. The media query solution is the right way to go about it though.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I tried adding the media query to the end of the stylesheet and unfortunately it didn't make a difference. I'll try changing the max height next.

Comment: Changing the height corrected the overlap, but it also completely messed up the rest of the formatting. [Screenshot here](http://s3.postimg.org/blw19xbhf/2015_03_11_11_06_35.png). Any ideas? :/

Comment: You should find the media query, which should already exist and then adding the element and style within that media query.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are facing this issue is because the `article` tag which wraps the `iframe` has a `CSS` property `max-height:320px` attached to it. Due to this, when you view in the mobile view, the `article` tag does not expand beyond 320px. As the width is also being decreased in the mobile view, the 320px height limitation causes the content to overlap rather than flow below it.

What you can do is override the 320px max height limit with something like this in your *media query* :

```
.home-content-modules-row .content-module {
    max-height: 1000px;
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Changing the height corrected the overlap, but it also completely messed up the rest of the formatting. [Screenshot here](http://s3.postimg.org/blw19xbhf/2015_03_11_11_06_35.png). Any ideas? :/

Comment: @LaurenShutt You need to add the code within the media query. The CSS file you have mentioned in the question already contains a  media query section. Just add the aforementioned code within that.